# Machine learning model bundled with a library vs. an API

Tags: python, predictive-modeling, data-product

I am thinking to "deploy" a machine learning model (in pickle it is sized 3 megabytes) and after discussing with my developer colleagues, they said it would be better if the model is packed as a python library instead of a microservice (like a rest API).

I wanted to ask what's your view on this: Pickled model packed in a library specifically meant for it vs. a rest API, pros and cons?

I was thinking that having it as a library could possibly be easier to use and wouldn't require to have to worry about deployment, web address etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advantages of deploying the model as a package is the code will be part of the monolith application and require no remote calls thus:

- No additional operational demands
- No external dependencies
- Faster
- Fewer security issues
- Same uptime as the rest of the application

In general, most features stay in a single monolith application until there is are specific reasons to create separate services.

Answer (score 0):

**Complexity**, just look at this simple deplyoment from [fast ai](https://github.com/render-examples/fastai-v3/blob/master/app/server.py). you get a web app in a couple of simple steps. Where as for restapi you need to know your way around a lot more libraries. For example the cool [fastapi](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi) (flask+more capabilities). [Example ap](https://github.com/nsidnev/fastapi-realworld-example-app)p

**Online Learning** there is no possibility to update (not trivial atleast) your model in the pickeled file. Because you restapi code is modularised this can be modified.

**Overhead** restAPi is designed to handle larger number of requests, and scale more easily.

**Modularity/Control** You define exactly how you interect with the client, more control but more complexity when using restAPI

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Never heard of fastapi, will have a look. But my question still holds: machine learning model packed as python library/package vs. rest API. I have seen some implementation of open source libraries on github that have pickle models as part of it. It would be interesting to see a contrast from people, when to go for this format and when to go for a rest API.